# Use of Scala by-name parameters

Tags: scala, pass-by-name

I am going through the book ["Functional Programming in Scala"](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) and have run across an example that I don't fully understand.

In the chapter on strictness/laziness the authors describe the construction of Streams and have code like this:

```
sealed trait Stream[+A]
case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]

object Stream {
    def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]) : Stream[A] = {
        lazy val head = hd
        lazy val tail = tl
        Cons(() => head, () => tail)
    }
    ...
}
```

The question I have is in the smart constructor (`cons`) where it calls the constructor for the `Cons` case class.  The specific syntax being used to pass the `head` and `tail` vals doesn't make sense to me.  Why not just call the constructor like this:

```
Cons(head, tail)
```

As I understand the syntax used it is forcing the creation of two Function0 objects that simply return the `head` and `tail` vals.  How is that different from just passing `head` and `tail` (without the `() =>` prefix) since the `Cons` case class is already defined to take these parameters by-name anyway?  Isn't this redundant?  Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is in `=> A` not being equal to `() => A`.

The former is pass by name, and the latter is a function that takes no parameters and returns an A.

You can test this out in the Scala REPL.

```
scala> def test(x: => Int): () => Int = x
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: () => Int
       def test(x: => Int): () => Int = x
                                        ^
```

Simply referencing `x` in my sample causes the parameter to be invoked. In your sample, it's constructing a method which defers invocation of x.

Comment: Yep.  Sorry about that.  As I mentioned to @Jesper I should have noticed the difference in the two constructors and didn't.  So `Cons` requires an explicit Function0 and `cons` constructs one for you (behind the scenes).  What gets passed to `Cons` is evaluated right away and what gets passed to `cons` is evaluated later.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right. When you pass by value it will be re-evaluated every time it is read as well.

Comment: Minor nitpick: `() => A` is the type of a function with a single, empty argument list. `(Unit) => A` would be the type of a function taking unit as an argument. `()` is not a valid type.

Comment: @Feuermurmel I've modified; you're right the wording was incorrect. I was trying to highlight that `()` is the `Unit` value. So `() => Int` is an identical type to `Unit => Int` but is slightly shorter.

Comment: @Nate `() => Int` and `Unit => Int` are not the same types: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/7V2DdXv/0. But anyways, thanks for fixing the answer! :)

Comment: @Feuermurmel Again, you are right! Thanks for teaching me something!

Answer (score 9):

First, you are assuming that `=> A` and `() => A` are the same. However, they are not. For example, the `=> A` can only be used in the context of passing parameters by-name - it is impossible to declare a `val` of type `=> A`. As `case class` parameters are always `val`s (unless explicitly declared `var`s), it is clear why `case class Cons[+A](h: => A, t: => Stream[A])` would not work.

Second, just wrapping a by-name parameter into a function with an empty parameter list is not the same as what the code above accomplishes: using `lazy val`s, it is ensured that both `hd` and `tl` are evaluated **at most once**. If the code read

```
Cons(() => hd, () => tl)
```

the original `hd` would be evaluated *every time* the `h` method (field) of a `Cons` object is invoked. Using a `lazy val`, `hd` is evaluated only the first time the `h` method of this `Cons` object is invoked, and the same value is returned in every subsequent invocation.

Demonstrating the difference in a stripped-down fashion in the REPL:

```
> def foo = { println("evaluating foo"); "foo" }
> val direct : () => String = () => foo
> direct()
evaluating foo
res6: String = foo
> direct()
evaluating foo
res7: String = foo
> val lzy : () => String = { lazy val v = foo; () => v }
> lzy()
evaluating foo
res8: String = foo
> lzy()
res9: String = foo
```

Note how the "evaluating foo" output in the second invocation of `lzy()` is gone, as opposed to the second invocation of `direct()`.

Comment: I'm not sure why a `val` cannot be of type `=> A`.  I got too lost in the weeds and didn't realize the difference between the definition of `Cons` and `cons`.  I *did* understand the use of the `lazy val` objects, though.  Thanks.

Comment: Along the same lines, aren't `hd` and `tl` val parameters?  And they *are* by-name.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `val` parameter. For me, the term `val` parameter only makes sense in the context of classes (`class A(x: String)` vs. `class B(val x: String)`). `cons`, as you pointed out, is a normal method. So why would `hd` and `tl` be `val` parameters?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I wasn't aware that parameters to functions could *not* be `var`.  I found some discussion about this after reading your comment and now realize that `var` parameters to functions are not allowed.  I was extending the `class B(var x: String)` construct to a normal function (incorrectly).

Answer (score 1):

Note that the parameters of the method `cons` are by-name parameters (`hd` and `tl`). That means that if you call `cons`, the arguments will not be evaluated before you call `cons`; they will be evaluated later, at the moment you use them inside `cons`.

Note that the `Cons` constructor takes two functions of type `Unit => A`, but *not* as by-name parameters. So these will be evaluated before you call the constructor.

If you do `Cons(head, tail)` then `head` and `tail` will be evaluated, which means `hd` and `tl` will be evaluated.

But the whole point here was to avoid calling `hd` and `tl` until necessary (when someone accesses `h` or `t` in the `Cons` object). So, you pass two anonymous functions to the `Cons` constructor; these functions will not be called until someone accesses `h` or `t`.

Comment: I got lost in the weeds and should have noticed the difference between the case class constructor and the smart constructor declarations.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]) : Stream[A]`

the type of `hd` is `A`, `tl` is `Stream[A]`

whereas in `case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]`

h is of type `Function0[A]` and t of type `Function0[Stream[A]]`

given the type of `hd` is `A`, the smart constructor invokes the case class as

```
 lazy val head = hd
 lazy val tail = tl
 Cons(() => head, () => tail) //it creates a function closure so that head is accessible within Cons for lazy evaluation
```