# Understanding syntax of a scala function

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying to learn scala. I know how to write a function. This is how I write a function.

```
def test_function: Unit = {
    println("This is just a test")
}
```

But then I started learning playframework. This is how they write a function in controller in play.

```
def test_function: Unit = Action{
    println("This is just a test")
}
```

My question is what is this Action doing before the curly braces? What is it called? How can I write my own? I hope I have made my question clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, that's *not* how you write a function, that's how you write a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this kind of behavior by defining an `apply` method on an `object` called `Action`:

```
object Action { 
  def apply(block: => Unit): Unit = {
    println("before")
    block                 // do the action in the block
    println("after") 
  }
}
```

Then both of these:

```
Action { println("hi") }
Action(println("hi"))
```

Produce this:

```
before
hi
after
```

The thing in braces after `Action` is just the argument to the `apply` method.  Scala allows either parentheses or braces, but using braces allows you to put multiple statements in:

```
Action {
  println("a")
  println("b")
}
```

yields:

```
before
a
b
after
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if it is not too much problem, then can you explain this line - block: => Unit

Comment: @eddard.stark That's [call-by-name syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26663219/1346276).

Answer (score 2):

`Action` is a trait (`play.api.mvc.Action`). Essentially it represents this type: `play.api.mvc.Request => play.api.mvc.Result` ([doc1](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaActions), [doc2](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.html)).

In your case you are using `Action {...}` which is equivalent to `Action(...)` and converted by compiler to `Action.apply(...)` call. If you check [source code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala) you'll see the `apply` method signatures defined not only on the `Action` trait and it's companion object, but also in here:

```
/**
 * Provides helpers for creating `Action` values.
 */
trait ActionBuilder[+R[_]] extends ActionFunction[Request, R]
```

In your case you are not taking any request and not producing any response, so essentially your `Action` is a function call of a form `apply(block: => Result)` where `Result` is thrown away since you define return type of your function as `Unit`.

`Action` supports many ways you can handle its body (including Futures) so pick the right `apply` method to cover your needs.

You can extend `Action` if you need to since it's not a final implementation. [Here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaActionsComposition) is an example:

```
case class Logging[A](action: Action[A]) extends Action[A]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Action` is basically a function alias of the shape `play.api.mvc.Request => play.api.mvc.Result`. When you see `Action { }`, you are actually seeing `apply` function of the companion object of that type and are passing a body that should provide that `Request => Result` function.

The companion object has roughly the shape of:

```
object Action {
  def apply(f: Request => Response): Action = ...
}
```

so that when you call `Action { ... }`, the `{ ... }` is that function that will be executed when the action is invoked.

In your example, `println("This is just a test")` serves as the provider of the `Result`.