# by value & by name in scala => one to one correspondence

Tags: scala, callbyname, pass-by-name

if when calling *by-value*

`val f: (Int) => Int = {(i) => {i * i}}        # f: Int => Int = <function1>` 

is the shorthand for

 
`val f: Function1[Int, Int] = {(i) => {i * i}} # f: Int => Int = <function1>`

then when calling *by-name*

`val f: (=> Int) => Int = {(i) => {i * i}} # f: (=> Int) => Int = <function1>`

is the shorthand for

**? what ?**

**and if**

when calling *by-value*

`val f = {(i) => {i * i}}:(Int) => Int        # f: Int => Int = <function1>` 

is the shorthand for

 
`val f = {(i) => {i * i}}:Function1[Int, Int] # f: Int => Int = <function1>`

then when calling *by-name*

`val f = {(i) => {i * i}}:(=>Int) => Int # f: (=> Int) => Int = <function1>`

is the shorthand for

**? what ?**

in other words

if **(Int) => Int** is shorthand for **Function1[Int, Int]**

then **(=> Int) => Int** is shorthand for **? what ?**

**Thank you !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't shorthand for anything. By-name types are by-name types. See SLS 4.6.1, http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#by-name-parameters.

It is true that if you look at the resulting bytecode, you will see that the argument will be passed as a `Function0`, but that's a bytecode-level implementation detail. At the language level, by-name types aren't just syntactic sugar. They are actual types (though they can only appear as parameter types, not in other contexts).

See also: [Use of Scala by-name parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26663219/86485)

Comment: Thanks Seth. I was afraid this would be the answer and frankly I don't like the fact. To me this is a language inconsistency. Anyways, it is good to know (at least for current Scala version 2.11.6) that no such equivalence exists. (I currently learn Scala trying to keep organized the stuff encountered, but in this case the pattern I was looking for didn't fit well)

Answer (score 1):

At the bytecode level, it's shorthand for :

```
Function1[Function0[Int], Int]
```

If you want to call such Scala code from another JVM language, you'll have to fullfill that signature.

See [the source code for Function0](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5e0880fe05fb65a8757721be7e5be6a3259c19a8/src/library/scala/Function0.scala), you won't find it in the scaladoc

Comment: Thanks Chirlo, but, it seems the signature for "Function1[Function0[Int], Int]" is "(() => Int) => Int = <function1>" and not "(=> Int) => Int = <function1>". Scala does not allow me to declare this (not even compile): "val f: Function1[Function0[Int], Int] = {(i) => {i * i}}" as equivalent of val f: (=> Int) => Int = {(i) => {i * i}}. An acceptable declaration would be "val f: Function1[Function0[Int], Int] = {(i) => i()}" though it is not the 1 to 1 equivalence

Comment: I updated my answer, which is based on the bytecode scalac generates.